# Remove blank page after end of chapter

Tags: double-sided, blank-page

I have used a double-paged template and it currently creates a blank page such that the new chapter always begins on the left side. However, my report is quite small and I would like to remove these blank pages. How do I do that?

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,b5paper,showtrims]{memoir}


% Stock and paper layout
\showtrimsoff
\pagebv
\setlrmarginsandblock{26mm}{20mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{35mm}{30mm}{*}
\setheadfoot{8mm}{10mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{7mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{18mm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{2mm}


\checkandfixthelayout                 % Check if errors!
\sideparmargin{outer}                 % Put sidemargins in outer position


% Chapterstyle
\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{mychapterstyle}{
    \chapterstyle{default}
    \def\format{\normalfont\sffamily}

    \setlength\beforechapskip{0mm}

    \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\format\LARGE}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\format\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont}
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\format\fontsize{32}{32}\selectfont}




    \setlength\midchapskip{1ex}

    \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\raggedleft \chaptitlefont ##1}
    \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\vskip0.5\onelineskip \hrule \vskip1.3\onelineskip}

}
\makeatother
\chapterstyle{mychapterstyle}

% Header and footer
\def\hffont{\sffamily\small}
\makepagestyle{myruled}
\makeheadrule{myruled}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeevenhead{myruled}{\hffont\thepage}{}{\hffont\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{myruled}{\hffont\rightmark}{}{\hffont\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{myruled}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{myruled}{}{}{}
\makepsmarks{myruled}{
    \nouppercaseheads
    \createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{}{\space}
    \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{\space}
    \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
    \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
    \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
    \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
    \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
    \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}
\pagestyle{myruled}
\copypagestyle{cleared}{myruled}      % When \cleardoublepage, use myruled instead of empty
\makeevenhead{cleared}{\hffont\thepage}{}{} % Remove leftmark on cleared pages

\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{}{}            % No page number on plain even pages (chapter begin)
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{}             % No page number on plain odd pages (chapter begin)

%

\begin{document}
%
\chapter{Discussion}
\chapter{Modelling}

\end{document}
```

Comment: class option `openany`

Comment: Have you tried the `openany` option to the document class?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: 'openany' worked great - thanks! A MWE has been added. Feel free to add an aswer.